# Could these organic golems exist?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, mythical-creatures, humanoid, robots

The organic golem is an artificial bionic humanoid. It is made up mostly of organic materials, like flesh and bone

Its limbs have tendons, ligaments, and bones like that of a human, but without muscles, instead having springs and other mechanisms attached to the bones. The hands and feet are not bionic, with the feet looking like ivory shoes with rough leather soles for traction, and the hands are mechanical pincers, and also made of ivory, though without any leather parts. Aside from the leather soles, they have no skin

The torso is human-like, but made of just bones without any flesh, besides the organs. The spine is springy, and can stand up on its own. The organs it has are a mechanical heart, 2 lungs, 2 kidneys, a bladder, a liver (that can create usable energy from electricity), a spleen, a battery, which is round, fleshy, and replaces the intestines and stomach, and 2 storage tanks, which store nutrients and are beside the spine, inferior to the kidneys

The neck is mostly mechanical. They have a head, which is a round skull without external flesh. They have no face, but instead just a single eye in the forehead

These organic golems are used for simple tasks such as manufacturing, carrying things, or finding trespassers

Could this organic golem function and do the tasks that it is designed for?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Their liver can recycle waste to create nourishment using the electric power from the battery, and extra nutrients can be added to the blood while it runs

Comment: Why does your golem need lungs and heart ? it cannot accommodate a blood stream in its skeleton-like body. What drives the springs.. I think this golem cannot  be viable. Maybe it can *exist*, but I wonder how it would move anywhere, let alone perform any tasks. Springs are passive mechanical components.

Comment: @Goodies There are other mechanisms besides the springs, and the blood passes through channels in the bones

Comment: What makes it move? Springs only react to a force, they do not generate force themselves. You need some motors or such. To me, it sounds like you are describing a robot made out of bones which of course is possible, I just don't see the use for the organs.

Comment: With exposed organs completely unprotected from external agents like bacteria and fungi? Probably not longer than a month in a best case scenario (and even if an immune system is present, unprotected organs will always be worse than protected ones). Emptying out bones to accommodate a system of blood vessels will both make them potentially more fragile and still not do the protecting job completely, since the joints will inevitably have exposed blood vessels. Also the skin is essentially one of the most important organs in our body, so I'd suggest keeping some of it at least.

Comment: So basically Mechanthralls?  In short, not without magically keeping the fleshy bit alive.  But if you are willing to ditch the organs and just have a humanoid skeleton used as a base to build a robot around, that might be somewhat doable with technology alone.

Comment: Without a brain? Am I missing a whole load?

Comment: the strength to weight ratio of muscle is one of the few advantages organics has why get rid of that and keep everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Difficult to say**

The question is mostly about if the flesh golem has movement power. The flesh seems alive, hence the ability to generate energy from electricity. The mechanics are uncertain, as we don't know what powers them. Compared to our *current* mechanics, it needs to be sophisticated. But as it's a fantasy setting, I'll give it a pass.

As the mechanics only need energy to move, it is the question how it gets there. As it still has a heart, lungs, liver and kidneys, we can assume a lot of energy is somehow transported by blood vessels. This needs to then be delivered at the mechanics. This also isn't impossible.

Where it breaks down is the flesh. It is very exposed even without the mechanics welded to the skin. Even if you can keep the flesh alive, it will suffer. Infection, disease, fungi and parasites. The golem is an easy prey. Even with a good immune system, you're running many risks due to the exposures. As the flesh deteriorates, the mechanical parts will not function as well. Especially when the organs get damaged.

If the still natural organs can be replaced, a normal golem would seem much more likely. Currently it seems an incredible investment. Grave robbing, advanced mechanics, batteries, bioengineering (liver producing energy from electricity) and directly attaching metals to the skin and inside the flesh, which might get rejected.

Without further handwaving, it seems this golem is a too high investment for the labour you get, as well as risks, before it falls apart. If these problems are solved, it would still need a way to get nutrients (hence the nutrient storage), but it doesn't seem to have a mouth and the stomach has been replaced.

If all that is fixed, it is okay in the designated tasks. The placement of storage tanks near the spine will limit it's movement with said spine, but it'll be functional. Do note that the feet and hands will need replacing every once in a while, as they'll wear down.